# ?4 being added to file name with this Bash script, why?

Tags: bash

I have this script that extracts one frame from a lot of `mp4` videos and store them as `png`

```
for i in *.mp4; do
    [ -f "$i" ] || break
    number=$(echo "$i" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
    name=frame"$number".png
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -ss 00:01:00.000 -vframes 1 "$name"
done
```

the videos are named like `video1.mp4`, `video2.mp4`, etc. Because the loop takes videos out of order, I extract the number from the video to generate the output file name.

This is working great but the file names of the `png` files are like this:

`frame1?4.png`, `frame3?4.png`, `frame3?4.png`...

why the `?4` ?

---

ah, I see now that the 4 comes from the 4 on mp4. How do I get just the first number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That `?` is just a placeholder character output by `ls` to represent the newline character that you have embedded in your file name.

```
echo foo3bar.mp4 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
```

would output:

```
3
4
```

As there are two sequences of 1 or more decimal digits in that file name.

Instead you could do:

```
for file in *[0-9]*.mp4; do
  n=${file%.*} # remove the extension
  n=${n%"${n##*[0-9]}"} # remove anything after the last digit
  n=${n##*[!0-9]} # remove everything up to the last non-digit.

  ffmpeg...
done
```

Which would extract the right-most sequence of decimal digits on the filename stripped of its extension and avoid running several commands for each file.

Note that that code only uses standard POSIX sh syntax, so you don't need `bash` to run it. With `bash` or other `ksh93`-like shells, if you know the root name of the file only contains one sequence of digits, you can also use:

```
n=${file%.*} # remove the extension
n=${n//[^0-9]} # remove all non-digit characters
```

With `bash`-specific features:

```
[[ $file =~ ([0-9]+).*\. ]] && n=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Would extract the *left-most* sequence of digits in the root name.

With `zsh`:

```
n=${(SM)${file:r}##<->}
```

Comment: BRILLIANT! WORKS PERFECTLY.

Comment: Could you say something about that second transformation and why it's needed? It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Ah, I see now. It's removing whatever might be _after_ the digits, before the extension.

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly identified that the `4` is coming from the `.mp4` extension in the filename.  The question mark is likely `ls` displaying the newline which `grep -o` inserts between each match (this is one of the reasons not to trust the filenames that `ls` displays, by the way).

To extract the first digit, or rather, the last digit before the `.mp4` extension, you may do

```
n=${i%.mp4}
number=${n##*[!0-9]}
```

This first strips the extension from the name in `i` and then strips all non-numerals from the beginning of that.

Comment: not working for me. `number` is coming empty.

Comment: @SpaceDog That's probably because I used `[^0-9]` (which worked for me in Bash 4.4) rather than `[!0-9]`.

Comment: `bash` has always recognised `^` as an alias for `!`. The shells that don't include the Bourne shell (where `^` is a pipe operator), ksh88 and posh. POSIX allows but does not mandate  `^` to be recognised as an alias for `!` so `[^0-9]` is either the same as `[!0-9]` or `[0-9^]` so shouldn't be used in POSIX scripts.